# Application of argument principle for $f(z)=z^3 e^{z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)=z^3e^{z^2}$ for $z \in \Bbb C$ and let $\Gamma$ be the circle $z=e^{i\theta}$,where $0\leq\theta\leq4 \pi.$ Then $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\Gamma} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz = \;?$$

Since $f$ is analytic inside and on $\Gamma$, by argument principle , $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\Gamma} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz =\text{number of zeros of f inside $\Gamma$}$$ but $f(z)=0$ if $z^3=0$ since $e^{z^2} \neq 0$, so $z=0$. So we have three zeros( with multiplicity). That is $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\Gamma} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz =3$$

But the answer given is $6$. What is the mistake here ? Any help ?

Comment: Isn't the winding number 2?

Comment: Can you explain your comment a bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument principle,  a quick check reveals, in full generality involves the winding number of the contour.

Since $0\le\theta\le4\pi$, the winding number is $2$.  The result is to multiply the answer by $2$.

Comment: I have one small doubt:   I know Unit circle has a representation $e^{i \theta}$, $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$. but here the range of $\theta$ is $4 \pi$.  so $\Gamma$ represents precisely which  circle ?

Comment: Same circle,  just going around twice.